# Javascript: overwriting object inside object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Why is 'a' doesn't change even after changing the value of 'name' which is passed as a key in an object?

How can we actually compare the whole object inside the object?

```js
const a = {
  name: "Laptop",
  age: 2,
  hasA: true,
}
let name = {
  mobile: true,
  number: 3
};
a[name] = true;
console.log(a[name]); // Output: true
name = {};
console.log(a[name]); // Output: true
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); // {"name":"Laptop","age":2,"hasA":true,"[object Object]":true}
```

Comment: You did not pass a key `a[{  mobile: true,  number: 3}]` is not a key - if you meant to change laptop to 'true' you need `a["name"] = true` What is expected utput?

Comment: `const a` why would a CONSTANT change?

Comment: `{}` toStrings to `[object Object]` so even if `name` is a filled object, or empty, its still `[object Object]` so the key is the same

Comment: @GrafiCode a is an object, that is a const does not change that the members of the object can change, only mean you cannot do `a = 'something else'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An object key cannot be another object, only a string or a symbol. There is no "*whole object inside the object*". Can you tell us what you were trying to achieve?